# how to remove 'builtin_function_or_method' object cannot be interpreted as an integer error

Tags: python-3.6

I am getting invalid literal error in line 6 and 8 how to i deal with it

```
num_of_test_cases = int(input())
num_of_lines = input
num_of_columns =input
while(True):
    num_of_test_cases = num_of_test_cases -1      
    for i in range(num_of_lines):
        i+=1
        for j in range(num_of_columns):
            j+=1
            if((i+j)%2==0):
                print("*")
            else:
                print(".")
        print("\n")
        return 0
```

Comment: What do you want this line to do?: `num_of_lines = input`.

Comment: i want to take integer input of number of lines from user but when i use num_of_lines = int(input()) then a different error poped up